# missing calendar days

Tags: calendar, sharepoint-calendar

I have a calendar as a webpart however I wanted to show the the days in the header right on top of the days.
 Here's how it is now:[image]

I wanted for it to have something like this:
[image]

Comment: 2010 or 2013? Are you using a OOTB calendar without any modifications?